# Display posts of the last 7 days

Tags: query-posts, date

I'm trying to display the 5 best rated posts of the last week (7 days) on my website, however I can't seem to figure out how to display them.

Here's what I've achieved so far but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php $slider_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&cat=3&orderby=highest_rated&order=desc'); ?>

<?php

$mylimit = 7 * 86400; //days * seconds per day

while ($slider_query->have_posts()) : $slider_query->the_post();

    $post_age = date('U') - get_post_time('U');

    if ($post_age < $mylimit) { 
?>

//The Post

<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Note that `orderby=highest_rated` isn't inbuilt in WordPress. Are you using some plugin for ratings?

Comment: Yes I am using a plugin for this :) Thank you for your concern!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In addition to birgire's solution, as of WordPress 3.7, you can use [Date parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Your arguments would look like this to filter posts from the last 7 days:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',

    // Using the date_query to filter posts from last week
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '1 week ago'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This should be the approach as from 3.7 :-)

Comment: This is good but it gets posts exactly 24*7 hours ago. In example, if it currently is night time, it won't retrieve posts published 7 days ago in the morning.

Answer (score 6):

I think this must have been solved many times here on WordPress Answers.

You could also check out the [examples in the Time parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) part in Codex for `WP_Query`.

Here are two of them (slightly modified to your needs)

**Example 1:**

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts in the last 7 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$slider_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&cat=3&orderby=highest_rated&order=desc');    
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

**Example 2:**

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts for May 1 to March 8, 2013
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '2013-05-01' AND post_date < '2013-05-8'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$slider_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&cat=3&orderby=highest_rated&order=desc');
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' )
```

assuming that you have this `orderby=highest_rated` covered with some plugin as you describe in the comment above.

Comment: I'm wondering whether if 'date_query' is better to use? By adding the following to the wp_query arguments:   'date_query' => array( array('after' => '1 week ago')

Comment: Yes, that would now be the preferred method, since the answer was written prior to the existence of the `date_query` parameter ;-)  @ChristineCooper

Answer (score 0):

From the [`WP_Query` Time Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) section:

Returns posts for just the current week:

```
$week = date('W');
$year = date('Y');
$query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $year . '&w=' . $week );
```

Comment: Hey. I haven't tested this yet, but I'm pretty sure it's not what I'm looking for exactly. This probably lists posts posted in week 13 for example. What I want is the posts that were posted in the past 7 days. So for example, from Wednesday 8 May until Wednesday 1 May.

Answer (score 0):

Working for me like this, to show post from last 7 days according to the number of views and order by post views count DESC.

```
                $date_range = strtotime ( '-7 day' );  
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'         => 'post',
                    'post_status'       => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page'    => '10',
                    'meta_key'          => 'post_views_count',
                    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order'             => 'DESC', 
                    'date_query'        => array(
                        array(
                            'after' => array(
                                'year'  => date('Y', $date_range ),
                                'month' => date('m', $date_range ),
                                'day'   => date('d', $date_range ),
                            ),
                        )
                    )
                );


                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use [wp_get_archives()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/)

```
 wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'weekly', 'limit' => 1, 'show_post_count' => 'true' ,'format'=>'option') ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

More Simple Using sql query wordpress hook **posts where**

```
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
$dto = new DateTime();
  $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
  $ret['week_start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  $dto->modify('+6 days');
  $ret['week_end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  return $ret;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse29897_no_parents', 10, 2 );
function wpse29897_no_parents( $where, $query )
{
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) && 'menu_plans' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] )
    {
        if( '' != $where )
    {
        
        $currentdate = date('Y-m-d');
        $currdate = new DateTime($currentdate);
        if($_GET['weekchk']){
            $currentweek = $_GET['weekchk'];
        }else{
            $currentweek = $currdate->format("W");
        }
        $week_array = getStartAndEndDate($currentweek,date('Y'));
        $ws = "'".$week_array['week_start']."'";
        $we = "'".$week_array['week_end']."'";
        $where .= " AND post_date >= ".$ws." AND post_date < ".$we."";
    }
    else
    {
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '2020-07-28' AND post_date < '2020-08-4'";
    }
}
return $where;
}
```